# Let's break constraints of Constrained Writing

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Motivated by ongoing [contest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/contest-ask-questions-earn-badges-win-prizes?cb=1), I was looking for less used writing areas on the site and make those areas more exposed, active and open to larger audiences. My [first question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42900/how-to-write-a-puzzle-without-being-too-descriptive-or-vague) after the contest's announcement, was driven by same motivation and I asked about writing puzzles, making the tag [puzzle-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-writing) (I will open another meta post for finalizing a proper wiki for the same).

Researching further I landed up over [Constrained Writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_writing). I realized that Constrained Writing is completely untouched area on our site. Before starting to ask questions on main site, I raised this meta post to clarify and get general consensus of community over following points:

1. Constrained writing is generically huge topic. It contains specific types/forms like Haiku, Sonnet, Anagrams,Abecedarius, Twiction etc. So is it okay to create a tag named "Constrained-Writing" OR shall separate tags be created for each specific type like Haiku, Sonnet etc?
2. Deciding scope and on-topicness of the topic as a whole in general.

Can I get the general overview of the community please?

Meanwhile, I have posted [one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43436/how-to-make-readers-know-that-my-write-up-has-used-a-hidden-constraint) question on the same topic on main site (because the contest will end soon and I want to make entry their. *Selfish me*). Do let me know if the question is unfit or happens to be off topic.

Comment: Just thought I'd point out, your question wouldn't qualify for the contest. Only tags with at least 10 questions qualify.

Comment: Some time ago I've posted a little guideline on how to rate new tag ideas under the question [I'd like some guidance on creating tags](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1498/23159). Just in case you want to get a feeling for it yourself or want some help on how to make a case for a new tag. I don't have the time to go through the points properly right now. Maybe later, but you might want to take a look.

Comment: @Galastel Thankfully that's not the only one tag used. Other tag hopefully would make it eligible for the entry

Comment: @Secespitus Thanks for the link. I'll surely keep that in mind.

Comment: Constraints like "no 'e'" or hidden messages feel different to me than constraints of *forms* (like haiku).  Maybe we shouldn't try to include poetic forms (some of which can have their own tags).

Answer (score 4):

I took off your [puzzle-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-writing) tag.  It's just too specific.  While we might want something to cover short pieces of creative writing (jokes, riddles, humor, captions, puzzles, memes, even tweets...some are fictional and some not), having a whole tag on puzzles seems like overkill.

I didn't remove [constrained-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constrained-writing) but I think we should discuss it.  It might be okay but I'm not convinced there's a need.  Also, while non-free verse poetry has constraints, it is *not* constrained writing and that is not an appropriate tag for it.  The appropriate tag for sonnets, haikus, and the like is [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry).

Note that, before seeing this Meta post, when I edited your constrained writing question, I added the [marketing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) tag.  So it qualifies for the contest, go ahead and enter!  As Galastel points out, your new tags don't qualify anyway.  That was done on purpose (thanks Monica!).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - Noted

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, "constrained writing" looks to me like an unnecessary tag. On the one hand, it is very broad. On the other, half of it (haiku, sonnets, acrostics, etc.) would fit under [poetry](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry). We also have a more specific [haiku](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haiku).

Twitter could perhaps fit under [social-media](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media).

The rest - anagrams etc. - *perhaps* we could have a more specific tag covering those, but excluding poetry. *If* there are multiple questions asking about it. Otherwise, [style](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) seems good enough to me. You can make your case if you find/ask more questions that would fit under such a tag.

Comment: Noted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Would an "**Experimental Writing**" tag work?  That would cover constrained writing (such as the [novel without an "e"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadsby_(novel))) , avant-garde bizarreness, and also people writing fiction that is deliberately playing with the fourth wall, or is layering symbolism upon symbolism (as a recent question had).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_literature

Comment: If I had a question about "writing a novel without an e", I wouldn't intuitively look for "experimental writing" as the tag that I'd want to apply. And if I encountered the tag, it wouldn't be self-explanatory - I'd have to read the tag wiki to figure out what it was about.

Comment: Sounds good and it seems to cover everything

Comment: Perhaps Experimental as the broad one, and constrained as a synonym?

Comment: It's not perfect but I can't come up with a better word.  Though I'm still not convinced it's needed at all.  If there are just a couple, they can go under [tag:technique]

Comment: I think like the "podcast" one being used to say "Yes, we are interested in answering questions related to writing a 'cast", an "experimental" one signals "hey, we're not only about the 3-act structure here".  It can also guide answer-ers as to what sort of answers are wanted.